# Common App GPA Scale

Tags: application

The Common Application asks for your school's GPA scale, but it's unbelievably confusing. There are lots of questions about this online, and there are even differences from school to school.

My high school has a weighted GPA system; if you take unweighted classes, it's on a 4.0 scale. Anything less than an A in unweighted courses will drop you below a 4.0. However, if you take weighted classes, you can get a "B" and still get a 4.0. If you get an A in the class, you can get higher than a 4.0.

Would I report my GPA scale on the Common App as 4.0 or 5.0? I did research and got a ridiculous number of mixed answers. I found [this Common App support page](https://membersupport.commonapp.org/membersupport/s/article/What-should-I-list-for-our-school-s-GPA-scale), but other schools suggest otherwise.

I've reported my GPA scale as 4.0 but reported my weighted GPA as 4.434. I've submitted applications to over half of the colleges I'm applying to, so I'm pretty sure I can't change my answers for those schools. I can still change the GPA scale before applying to other schools.

I only came to ask this question after a friend asked me. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Questions about undergraduate admissions are called out as off-topic here (see https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/what-kind-of-undergraduate-questions-are-not-really-generalizable-to-graduate-ed)

Answer (score 5):

I worked university IT for a bit before returning to academia. You made the correct decisions. At my university, we would get pipe separated values containing your GPA scale which is the 4.0 scale and your reported GPA which could be greater than the scale. Our internal database had fields for both and were fairly flexible. This should be the case for most universities, so you should be in the clear.